# UITableView does not show data in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

please help me with this problem.
I cannot find any problem for the last 4 days and nights.
This is the simple job that I already did in another project.
But the different thing is that this is my first time to use UISearchBar with Display Controller.
Anyway here are my codes.

mnuSearch.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "constants.h"
#import "JSON.h"
#import "Initial.h"

@interface mnuSearch : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate> {

}

@property (retain) NSMutableArray *_arrSearchNews;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISearchBar *txtSearchBox;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tblNewsSearch;

@end
```

mnuSearch.m

```
#import "mnuSearch.h"

@interface mnuSearch ()

@end

@implementation mnuSearch

@synthesize _arrSearchNews;
@synthesize txtSearchBox, tblNewsSearch;

#pragma mark - When "search button" in keyboard is clicked
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [self searchNews:searchBar.text];
    [self.tblNewsSearch reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - Search news
-(void)searchNews:(NSString*)query {
    // Retrieve searched news list
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mydomain.com/NewsSearch.ashx?a=%@&b=%@&c=%@", currentLocale, uniqueID, [Initial getUrlEncode:query]];
    NSURLRequest *_rqJsonDataList = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    NSData *_rpJsonDataList = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:_rqJsonDataList returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *_strJsonDataList = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_rpJsonDataList encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *_nsDicJsonDataList = [_strJsonDataList JSONValue];
    NSString *_strStatusCode = [_nsDicJsonDataList objectForKey:@"StatusCode"];
    NSString *_strStatusMessage = [_nsDicJsonDataList objectForKey:@"StatusMessage"];

    // OK
    if ([_strStatusCode isEqualToString:@"OK"]) {
        NSArray *_arrList = [_nsDicJsonDataList objectForKey:@"Table1"];
        [self._arrSearchNews removeAllObjects];
        [self._arrSearchNews addObjectsFromArray:_arrList];
    }
    // Error
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil
                                                   message:_strStatusMessage
                                                  delegate:nil
                                         cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                         otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];


        [alert show];
    }
}

#pragma mark - [UITableView] Number of Sections
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

#pragma mark - [UITableView] Number of Rows In Section
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    int _retValue = 0;

    _retValue = [_arrSearchNews count];

    return _retValue;
}

#pragma mark - [UITableView] Return table view cell
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"mnuSearchCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    // Set font
    UIFont *textLabelFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
    cell.textLabel.font = textLabelFont;
    UIFont *detailTextLabelFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = detailTextLabelFont;

    cell.imageView.image = nil;

    NSDictionary *_nsDic = [self._arrSearchNews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *abc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@] %@", [_nsDic objectForKey:@"GUBUN_NM"], [_nsDic objectForKey:@"TSUBJECT"]];
    NSLog(@"%@", abc);    **//--> This returns text I wanted.**
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@] %@", [_nsDic objectForKey:@"GUBUN_NM"], [_nsDic objectForKey:@"TSUBJECT"]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;

    return cell;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self._arrSearchNews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setTblNewsSearch:nil];
    [self setTxtSearchBox:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
@end
```

I really don't understand why my UITableView does not return any data.
When I type in some keywords in Search Box, it shows me "No Results".
And when I click "Search" in keyboard, my app gets data from json.
"_arrSearchNews" has got 340 objects.
But UITableView still remains with "No Results".
Please help me with this error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You added UISearchBarDelegate and UISearchDisplayDelegate but you didnt implement the delegate methods...

Comment: I did. - (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar. And that does not mean my UITableView shouldn't return any data, does it?

Answer (score 0):

UISearchDisplayController shows a tableView with the search results overlayed on top of your normal tableView, so you need to make sure to properly set the searchResultsDelegate and searchResultsDataSource  of the searchDispllayController so it knows how to populate the tableView.